# Are JSON values valid JSON?

Tags: json

Are JSON values string, number, true, false, null valid JSON?
I.e., is

```
true
```

a valid JSON document? Or does is have to be an array/object?

Some validators accept this (e.g. http://jsonlint.com/), while others do not (e.g. http://jsonschemalint.com/). The RFC and json.org are not clear on this issue.

Comment: The RFC is indeed clear on this issue.

Comment: This has been re-asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json/18419527) and received more detailed answers. I propose this be marked as a duplicate and the newer question kept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of March 2014: **Yes**. [From the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159):

> A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous
> specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an
> array.  Implementations that generate only objects or arrays where a
> JSON text is called for will be interoperable in the sense that all
> implementations will accept these as conforming JSON texts.

However, **at the time this question was originally asked**, the answer was: No. [The original specification said](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627):

> A JSON text is a serialized object or array

So the outer-most data type in a JSON text had to be either an object or an array, it couldn't be a string, boolean, number or any other data type.

Comment: While this answer is correct according to the official spec, it's interesting to note that JSON.parse(42) seems to work in browsers.

Comment: Just a technical note - the RFC you mentioned is for "The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation". Not for the JSON format as such. Neither http://www.json.org/ nor ECMA-404 state this (afaik). I personally find it weird that [42] is valid JSON and simple 42 is not.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569221/did-the-publication-of-ecma-404-affect-the-validity-of-json-texts-such-as-2-or (noting the publication date of ecma-404 and this answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to ECMA-404 The JSON Data Interchange Standard.

Source: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens formed from Unicode code points that conforms to the JSON value grammar.

And following, the JSON value grammar is given as:

> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.

This directly conflicts with the RFC, as cited by @quentin. The updated RFC is 8259 which states:

> Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array.   Implementations that generate only objects or arrays where a
>   JSON text is called for will be interoperable in the sense that all implementations will accept these as conforming JSON texts.